# Problem to convert to pinescript V4 or V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I have this code in my account and it works fine but I can not publish it. I'm having a very hard time converting this script to the version 4 or 5.

```js
study(title="Wolf Trade", overlay = true)
adverupgrade = input(defval=true,  title="instagram.com/wolftrade_official")
showsignal   = input(defval=true,  title="Signal")
showStop     = input(defval=false,  title="Stop Loss")
a = input(2, title = "Sensitive 1 Or 2")
RSILENGTH = input(14, title = "14")
RSICENTERLINE = input(52, title = "52")
MACDFASTLENGTH = input(7, title = "7")
MACDSLOWLENGTH = input(12, title = "12")
MACDSIGNALSMOOTHING = input(12, title = "12")
SmoothK = input(3, title = "3")     
SmoothD = input(3, title = "3")
LengthRSI = input(14, title = "14")
LengthStoch = input(14, title = "14")
c = input(10, title="10")
xATR = atr(c)
nLoss = a * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
                    iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                        iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))
pos =  iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
      iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
color = pos == -200 ? red: pos == 1 ? yellow : yellow 
ema= ema(close,1)
above = crossover(ema,xATRTrailingStop )
below = crossover(xATRTrailingStop,ema)
buy = close > xATRTrailingStop and above 
sell = close < xATRTrailingStop and below
barbuy = close > xATRTrailingStop 
barsell = close < xATRTrailingStop 
plotshape(showsignal and buy, title = "Buy", text = 'Buy', style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color= #00bcd4,textcolor = #00bcd4, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(showsignal and sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color= #e91c1c,textcolor = #e91c1c, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
barcolor(showsignal and barbuy? #26a69a:na)
barcolor(showsignal and barsell? #ef5350:na)
alertcondition(showsignal and buy, title='Buy', message='Buy')
alertcondition(showsignal and sell, title='Sell', message='Sell')
Length=input(title="22", type=integer, defval=22)
ATRPeriod=input(title="22", type=integer, defval=22)
Mult=input(title="3", type=integer, defval=3)
RSISource = input(close, title = "close")
SOURCE = input(hlc3, title = "hlc3")
short_stop = lowest(Length)+Mult*atr(ATRPeriod)
long_stop  = highest(Length)-Mult*atr(ATRPeriod)
shortvs=na(shortvs[1]) ? short_stop : iff(close>shortvs[1], short_stop , min(short_stop,shortvs[1]))
longvs=na(longvs[1]) ? long_stop : iff(close<longvs[1], long_stop, max(long_stop,longvs[1]))
longswitch=iff (close>=shortvs[1] and close[1]<shortvs[1] , 1 ,  0)
shortswitch=iff (close<=longvs[1] and close[1]>longvs[1] ,  1 ,  0)
direction= iff(na(direction[1]), 0, 
            iff (direction[1]<=0 and longswitch, 1, 
            iff (direction[1]>=0 and shortswitch, -1, direction[1])))
pc=direction>0?longvs:shortvs
plot(showStop and pc ? pc : na, color=direction>0?#26a69a:#ef5350, title="Stop Lines", style=line, transp=70, linewidth=2)
```

I tried a lot but I could not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a v4 indicator, it's written in Pine v1, hence why it works without specifying the version at the beginning. Migration guides from earlier Pine versions to the newer ones can be found [in the User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html).

Working v5 code:

```js
    //@version=5
    indicator(title='Wolf Trade', overlay=true)
    adverupgrade = input(defval=true, title='instagram.com/wolftrade_official')
    showsignal = input(defval=true, title='Signal')
    showStop = input(defval=false, title='Stop Loss')
    a = input(2, title='Sensitive 1 Or 2')
    RSILENGTH = input(14, title='14')
    RSICENTERLINE = input(52, title='52')
    MACDFASTLENGTH = input(7, title='7')
    MACDSLOWLENGTH = input(12, title='12')
    MACDSIGNALSMOOTHING = input(12, title='12')
    SmoothK = input(3, title='3')
    SmoothD = input(3, title='3')
    LengthRSI = input(14, title='14')
    LengthStoch = input(14, title='14')
    c = input(10, title='10')
    xATR = ta.atr(c)
    nLoss = a * xATR
    float xATRTrailingStop = na
    iff_1 = close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? close - nLoss : close + nLoss
    iff_2 = close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss) : iff_1
    xATRTrailingStop := close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss) : iff_2
    float pos = na
    iff_3 = close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)
    pos := close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? 1 : iff_3
    color = pos == -200 ? color.red : pos == 1 ? color.yellow : color.yellow
    ema = ta.ema(close, 1)
    above = ta.crossover(ema, xATRTrailingStop)
    below = ta.crossover(xATRTrailingStop, ema)
    buy = close > xATRTrailingStop and above
    sell = close < xATRTrailingStop and below
    barbuy = close > xATRTrailingStop
    barsell = close < xATRTrailingStop
    plotshape(showsignal and buy, title='Buy', text='Buy', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#00bcd4, 0), textcolor=color.new(#00bcd4, 0), size=size.tiny)
    plotshape(showsignal and sell, title='Sell', text='Sell', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#e91c1c, 0), textcolor=color.new(#e91c1c, 0), size=size.tiny)
    barcolor(showsignal and barbuy ? #26a69a : na)
    barcolor(showsignal and barsell ? #ef5350 : na)
    alertcondition(showsignal and buy, title='Buy', message='Buy')
    alertcondition(showsignal and sell, title='Sell', message='Sell')
    Length = input(title='22', defval=22)
    ATRPeriod = input(title='22', defval=22)
    Mult = input(title='3', defval=3)
    RSISource = input(close, title='close')
    SOURCE = input(hlc3, title='hlc3')
    short_stop = ta.lowest(Length) + Mult * ta.atr(ATRPeriod)
    long_stop = ta.highest(Length) - Mult * ta.atr(ATRPeriod)
    float shortvs = na
    float longvs = na
    shortvs := na(shortvs[1]) ? short_stop : close > shortvs[1] ? short_stop : math.min(short_stop, shortvs[1])
    longvs := na(longvs[1]) ? long_stop : close < longvs[1] ? long_stop : math.max(long_stop, longvs[1])
    longswitch = close >= shortvs[1] and close[1] < shortvs[1] ? 1 : 0
    shortswitch = close <= longvs[1] and close[1] > longvs[1] ? 1 : 0
    float direction = na
    iff_4 = direction[1] >= 0 and shortswitch ? -1 : direction[1]
    iff_5 = direction[1] <= 0 and longswitch ? 1 : iff_4
    direction := na(direction[1]) ? 0 : iff_5
    pc = direction > 0 ? longvs : shortvs
    plot(showStop and pc ? pc : na, color=direction > 0 ? color.new(#26a69a, 70) : color.new(#ef5350, 70), title='Stop Lines', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
```